# how to apply bootstrap tooltip to a dynamic generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have table that get populated with data from the database, i would like to add bootstrap tooltip this this, so when someone hoverover a row in a table his detail will get display. within that tool tip i would like to add a image, can i do that inside the toolt? This is my dynamic generated table.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#DisplayTable').tooltip({
        'show': true,
        'placement': 'bottom',
        'title': "Please remember to..."
    });
});

function Table(x) {
    var statusCol = "";
    var table = '<table><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Surname</th></tr>';
    var ID = 0;
    for (var student in x) {

        var row = '<tr class=\'staff-row\'id=\'' + x[id].ID + '\'</tr>';
        var row = '<tr class=\'staff-data\'id=\'' + x[id].Age + '\'</tr>';

        row += '<td>' + x[student].fNanme + '</td>';
        row += '<td>' + x[student].sName + '</td>'
        row += '<td>' + x[student].username + '</td>'
        ID++;
        table += row;
    }
    table += '</table>';
    $('#DisplayTable').html(table);
    $('#DisplayTable').tooltip({
    'show': true,
    'selector':'.staff-row, .staff-data',
    'placement': 'bottom',
    'title': function(event){
        var tds=$(this).find('td');            
        var tds=$(this).find(x[id].Age);            
        return $(tds[0]).text()+" "+$(tds[1]).text()+$(tds[3]).text();
    },        
});

}
```

> but tooltip dont work when i hover over the records?

```
        function Method(a,b,c) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/method.asmx/SomeMethod",
            data: JSON.stringify({ a: a, b: b, c: c }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try to set:

```
$('#DisplayTable').tooltip({
        'show': true,
        'placement': 'bottom',
        'title': "Please remember to..."
    });
```

instead of `$('#DisplayTable').tooltip('show');`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lks5L/4/) example:

```
<div id="DisplayTable"><span>Some template text</span></div>
<input type="button" id="clickMe" value="clickMe"/>

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
        Table(1);
    });
});

function Table(x) {
    var statusCol = "";
    var table = '<table><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Surname</th></tr>';
    var ID = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {

        var row = "<tr age='"+(12+i)+"' class='staff-row' id='" +"ColId"+i + "'>";

        row += '<td>' + "FName" + '</td>';
        row += '<td>' + "SName" + '</td>'
        row+="</tr>"
        ID++;
        table += row;
    }
    table += '</table>';
    $('#DisplayTable').html(table);
    $('#DisplayTable').tooltip({
        'show': true,
        'selector':'.staff-row',
        'placement': 'bottom',
        'title': function(event){
            var $this=$(this);
            var tds=$this.find('td');            
            return $(tds[0]).text()+" "+$(tds[1]).text()+" age: "+$this.attr("age");
        },        
    });
}
```

Comment: i replaced $('#DisplayTable').tooltip('show'); with the above code, but its not working. my table is generated base on database. can that be a reason why its not wokring

Comment: it works:) on more question if i have a method shown in my updated question how would i pass object a, b and c to tooltip? a= the person age, b=his marriage status and c= country his from? but i dont want that information to display in my table

Comment: you can set them as data attributes to <tr> tag: like <tr age="21" marriage="married"><td></td></tr> - and then just read it with jQuery $(this).attr("age");

Comment: i have updated my question, i have added additional parameters to my selector: and the data i am getting from the database so i created another var row etc...for the Age. But its not working?

Comment: i have updated my code, it works when i return $(tds[3]).text(). but it returns username which is the third column in my table. what if i want to get a person's age. So i have created tooltip for information that is not included in my table like age. So information like age marriageStatus etc.. will go in my tool-tip.

Comment: I updated answer and jsfiddle link. I hope this is the answer to your question.

Comment: @Dip , please look above